# raspberry pi addEvent. Runtime error:Failed to add edge detection

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am writing python code on raspberry pi 3. I am registering an event on input channel 21, to check moisture detection. I am getting this error Runtime error:Failed to add edge detection.
My code is:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys,os
import time
import datetime


channel = 21
led_output = 18
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(led_output, GPIO.OUT)


def callback(channel):
    filehandle = open("output.txt", "w") or die ("Could not write out")
    if GPIO.input(channel) == 1:
        print ("Water Detected!")
        filehandle.write("1")
        GPIO.output(led_output, GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        print ("Water Not Detected!")
        filehandle.write("0")
        GPIO.output(led_output, GPIO.HIGH)
    filehandle.close()




 GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH, bouncetime=300)   
 GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, callback)  

    print(GPIO.input(channel))

    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I reboot the Raspberry and run your code it works perfect.
Only after killing the process or CTRL-C keyboard interrupting and running it again the problem/error occurs. I think this has to do with the fact that you exit the program without cleaning up properly...
I got it working in case you exit the running the program with CTRL-C with the code below in which I included a **GPIO.cleanup()**
However...this unfortunately it does not cover the situation in which you simply kill the running programm...In that case you still need to reboot.
So there is room for improvement.
Please re-insert your own file management commands again.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
import sys,os
import time
import datetime

channel = 21
led_output = 18
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(led_output, GPIO.OUT)

def callback(channel):
    if GPIO.input(channel) == 1:
        print ("Water Detected!")
        GPIO.output(led_output, GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        print ("Water Not Detected!")
        GPIO.output(led_output, GPIO.HIGH)

GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH, bouncetime=300)   
GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, callback)  
print(GPIO.input(channel))


try:
    while True:
        #main loop here with some (dummy) code
        eg_set_a_dummy_variable = 0

except KeyboardInterrupt:  
    # here you put any code you want to run before the program   
    # exits when you press CTRL+C  
    print ("Program interrupted by CTRL-C")

except:  
    # this catches ALL other exceptions including errors.  
    # You won't get any error messages for debugging  
    # so only use it once your code is working  
    print ("Other error or exception occurred!") 

finally:
     # this ensures a clean exit and prevents your
     # error "Runtime error:Failed to add edge detection"
     # in case you run your code for the second time after a break
    GPIO.cleanup()

     # credits to:
     # https://raspi.tv/2013/rpi-gpio-basics-3-how-to-exit-gpio-programs-cleanly-avoid-warnings-and-protect-your-pi
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clean solution, but you can call `GPIO.cleanup()` at the start of your script too for case when your process was killed before and `GPIO.cleanup()` was not called.