RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection
I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 for vibration sensor with the following code:
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

#GPIO SETUP
channel = 27
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN)

def callback(channel):
        if GPIO.input(channel):
                print ("Movement Detected!")
        else:
                print ("Movement Detected!")

GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH, bouncetime=300)  # let us know when the pin goes HIGH or LOW
GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, callback)  # assign function to GPIO PIN, Run function on change

# infinite loop
while True:
        time.sleep(1)

and produces an error like this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/project/project.py", line 16, in <module>
    GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH, bouncetime=300)  # let us know when the pin goes HIGH or LOW
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection

How can I fix this?

You may find an answer in this stackoverflow subject : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53245060/raspberry-pi-addevent-runtime-errorfailed-to-add-edge-detection
